# WHOIS API JSON Array Content

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, api

I am in need of some help. As I have been breaking my balls on this for nearly five hours now I am getting a little frustrated, as you may imagine.

My frustration is mostly caused by my inexperience with JSON arrays, especially more complicated arrays and how to process them in PHP. Whatever I've tried so far to amend the example code below has resulted in a large number of errors or no script execution whatsoever...

I am using the following service -> [WHOIS API](https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whois-api-guide.php) for looking up data pertaining to a certain domain/IP.

The service returns a JSON array, like this one for example:`

```
{
  "WhoisRecord": {
    "createdDate": "1997-09-15T00:00:00-0700",
    "updatedDate": "2015-06-12T10:38:52-0700",
    "expiresDate": "2020-09-13T21:00:00-0700",
    "registrant": {
      "name": "Dns Admin",
      "organization": "Google Inc.",
      "street1": "Please contact contact-admin@google.com, 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "state": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94043",
      "country": "UNITED STATES",
      "email": "dns-admin@google.com",
      "telephone": "16502530000",
      "fax": "16506188571",
      "rawText": "Registrant Name: Dns Admin\nRegistrant Organization: Google Inc.\nRegistrant Street: Please contact contact-admin@google.com, 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway\nRegistrant City: Mountain View\nRegistrant State/Province: CA\nRegistrant Postal Code: 94043\nRegistrant Country: US\nRegistrant Phone: +1.6502530000\nRegistrant Fax: +1.6506188571\nRegistrant Email: dns-admin@google.com"
    },
    "administrativeContact": {
      "name": "DNS Admin",
      "organization": "Google Inc.",
      "street1": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "state": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94043",
      "country": "UNITED STATES",
      "email": "dns-admin@google.com",
      "telephone": "16506234000",
      "fax": "16506188571",
      "rawText": "Admin Name: DNS Admin\nAdmin Organization: Google Inc.\nAdmin Street: 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway\nAdmin City: Mountain View\nAdmin State/Province: CA\nAdmin Postal Code: 94043\nAdmin Country: US\nAdmin Phone: +1.6506234000\nAdmin Fax: +1.6506188571\nAdmin Email: dns-admin@google.com"
    }
  }
}`
```

All I am interested in is the WhoisRecord -> registrant part (name, organization, street1, city, state, postalcode, country, email, etc. etc.)

So far, so good.

However when I run the PHP code example they provide with their API stuff starts to become a bit confusing to me. The code is displayed below:

```
  <?php
  $username="YOUR_USERNAME";
  $password="YOUR_PASSWORD";    
  $contents = file_get_contents("http://www.whoisxmlapi.com//whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=google.com&username=$username&password=$password&outputFormat=JSON");
  //echo $contents;
  $res=json_decode($contents);
  if($res){
    if($res->ErrorMessage){
        echo $res->ErrorMessage->msg;
    }   
    else{
        $whoisRecord = $res->WhoisRecord;
        if($whoisRecord){
            echo "Domain name: " . print_r($whoisRecord->domainName,1) ."<br/>";
            echo "Created date: " .print_r($whoisRecord->createdDate,1) ."<br/>";
            echo "Updated date: " .print_r($whoisRecord->updatedDate,1) ."<br/>";
            if($whoisRecord->registrant)echo "Registrant: <br/><pre>" . print_r($whoisRecord->registrant->rawText, 1) ."</pre>";
            //print_r($whoisRecord);
        }
    }
  }

?>
```

I immediately get slammed with the following error when I execute it, the amount of errors increases when certain data is missing (for example the registrant's name).

> **Notice**:  Undefined property: stdClass::$ErrorMessage in
>   **/home/users/pcsnlftp/india.pcs-nl.com/includes/scripts/test/test-processor.php**
>   on line **47**
>  Domain name: google.com
> Created date:
>   1997-09-15T00:00:00-0700
> Updated date:
>   2015-06-12T10:38:52-0700
> Registrant: 
>  Registrant Name: Dns
>   Admin  Registrant Organization: Google Inc.  Registrant Street: Please
>   contact contact-admin@google.com, 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Registrant
>   City: Mountain View  Registrant State/Province: CA  Registrant Postal
>   Code: 94043  Registrant Country: US  Registrant Phone:+1.6502530000 
>   Registrant Fax: +1.6506188571  Registrant Email: dns-admin@google.com

My question is two pronged;

1. How do I get rid of the errors which basically serve no purpose (to me)?
2. How do I get the required data into variables which I could, for example, insert into a MySQL database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if(isset($res->ErrorMessage))` should solve your first question.... and for second just use for example `$domain=$whoisRecord->domainName` instead of whole echo thing

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying, please excuse my ignorance on this; but if it would be as simple as `$domain=$whoisRecord->domainName` why are they using `print_r`?

Comment: print_r($variable,1) returns the value.... more details at  http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
<?php
  $username="YOUR_USERNAME";
  $password="YOUR_PASSWORD";    
  $contents = file_get_contents("http://www.whoisxmlapi.com//whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=google.com&username=$username&password=$password&outputFormat=JSON");
  $res=json_decode($contents, true);
  if($res){
    if(isset($res['ErrorMessage'])){
        echo $res['ErrorMessage'];
    } else {
        if(isset($res['WhoisRecord'])){
            echo "Domain name: " . $res['WhoisRecord']['domainName']."<br/>";
            echo "Created date: " .$res['WhoisRecord']['createdDate']."<br/>";
            echo "Updated date: " .$res['WhoisRecord']['updatedDate']."<br/>";
            if(isset($res['WhoisRecord']['registrant']))
                echo "Registrant: <br/><pre>" . $res['WhoisRecord']['registrant']['rawText'] ."</pre>";
        }
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try the code in a few hours and report back!

Answer (score 1):

Use this for fetching data from json array.

```
echo "Name".$res['WhoisRecord']['registrant']['name'];
echo "Organization".$res['WhoisRecord']['registrant']['organization'];
```

If it doesn't work then first `$res=json_decode($contents);` to `$res=json_decode($contents, true);` and then use this

```
echo "Name".$res['WhoisRecord']['registrant']['name'];
echo "Organization".$res['WhoisRecord']['registrant']['organization'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try the code in a few hours and report back! This is a variant of fetching data I had not tried yet.

Comment: Damnit, when using the following code; 
`$res=json_decode($contents);
  if($res){
    $whoisRecord = $res->WhoisRecord;
    if($whoisRecord){
   echo "Name".$res['WhoisRecord']['registrant']['name'];
    }
   }`

I get the following error:
`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>/home/users/pcsnlftp/india.pcs-nl.com/includes/scripts/test/test-processor.php</b> on line <b>49</b><br />`

Comment: When adding `,true` to the json_decode I get the following error: `<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/home/users/pcsnlftp/india.pcs-nl.com/includes/scripts/test/test-processor.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />`